# CMD busybox doesn't work in task definition health check

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

In my Dockerfile, I have created a healthcheck

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=2s --start-period=5s --retries=3 CMD ["busybox", "nc", "-z", "localhost", "12345"]
```

This health check is working in the Docker environment as my container is displaying healthy in `docker ps` STATUS.

Now, I wanted to replicate the same health check method in ECS task definition and had set the Healthcheck `Command` in AWS Console to be

```
CMD, busybox, nc -z localhost 12345
```

But the Task `Health Status` is always displaying `UNHEALTHY. Is my configuration wrong? Does AWS ECS support non-shell command health check?

Sidenote: I'm running a fluentbit:1.4-debug image that has busybox available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by having comma separated for all argument and `nc` directly. So the final `Command` looks like

```
CMD,nc,-z,localhost,12345
```